# How to upgrade a go module behind a replace directive?

Tags: go, go-modules

Here is my `go.mod`

```
require(
    git.myorg.com/foo v0.0.0-20220124220940-064ec2185f3a
)

replace git.myorg.com/foo => git.myorg.com/myteam/foo vv0.0.0-20220202233523-3fe23663418f

module my-project-demo

go 1.16
```

Now I want to upgrade the package `foo`, I tried:

`go get -u git.myorg.com/foo`, it upgrades some other module's version but the module `foo` doesn't get upgraded;

I also tried `go get -u git.myorg.com/myteam/foo`, but got error message

```
parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: git.myorg.com/foo
                but was required as: git.myorg.com/myteam/foo
```

How to upgrade this `foo` module to latest version? Thanks!

Comment: By manually updating the replace directive to whatever "version" you want foo to be? The replace stuff is not some magic indirection it is some kind of **manual intervention/override**. Focus on "manual" as in "all tooling gone".

Comment: why are you using still go 1.16 ?

Answer (score 0):

**To upgrade a Go module behind a replace directive, follow these steps:**

**1. Check the latest version of the module:**

```bash
go list -m -versions git.myorg.com/myteam/foo
```

**2. Update the version in the replace directive:**

Open your `go.mod` file and modify the replace directive:

```golang
replace git.myorg.com/foo => git.myorg.com/myteam/foo v1.2.3
```

you have to Replace `v1.2.3` with the latest version obtained in step 1.

**3. Run `go get` to upgrade the module:**

```bash
go get -u git.myorg.com/foo
```

This command updates the module to the latest version specified in the replace directive.

**4. Tidy up dependencies:**

```bash
go mod tidy
```

This ensures that the `go.mod` file is clean and reflects the correct dependencies.

**Additional Considerations:**

- **Module Path Consistency:** Ensure the module path in the `require` and `replace` directives matches the actual module path declared in `git.myorg.com/foo`'s `go.mod` file.
- **Local Development:** If using a local version or fork, consider using a branch-based replace directive (e.g., `replace git.myorg.com/foo => ../myteam/foo`) for local development.
- **Vendoring:** For strict control over the version, use vendoring to lock down the specific version of `git.myorg.com/foo` in your project.

Comment: Actually the `go list -m -versions` doesn't work for me, I used a workaround: `go get -u git.myorg.com/myteam/foo`, the warning message contains the latest pseduco version: `go: git.myorg.com/myteam/foo@v0.0.0-20240125014612-8632dd797987`, then I manually updates the `go.mod`. I am not sure if there is an "official way" to upgrade it.

Comment: @codewarrior  this command gives output like this ` go list -m -versions github.com/gin-gonic/gin`                        
`github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.1.1 v1.1.2 v1.1.3 v1.1.4 v1.3.0 v1.4.0 v1.5.0 v1.6.0 v1.6.1 v1.6.2 v1.6.3 v1.7.0 v1.7.1 v1.7.2 v1.7.3 v1.7.4 v1.7.5 v1.7.6 v1.7.7 v1.8.0 v1.8.1 v1.8.2 v1.9.0 v1.9.1`